# WU-spaces and H-spaces

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory, operads

A WU-space of Boardman and Vogt [BV] is an algebra over the W-construction of the associative operad.

[BV] define H-spaces assuming a multiplication with homotopy unit e, and the homotopies must be ponited, that is, fix e.

I would like to see that any WU-space induces a H-space and I am be able to see that they have a homotopy unit e but I do not see if the homotopies giving by trees fix e.

Some hint, please?